# Copy multiple files to multiple clients

Tags: ssh, scp, sftp, deployment

I want to deploy multiple files on multiple remote machines, what is the best way ( other than ssh's ssh-key ). Is there any lightweight service for this ?

For example, I have 15 files which should be deployed to 10 remote machines.
The process should be automated

Comment: Try `man rsync`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the best way for my case was to generate a .pem on server where I wanted to deploy files into.

On server (VM in my case) :

```
1- generate ssh key : ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048

2- cat keyName.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys

3- chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys

4- create pem file : openssl rsa -in id_rsa -outform pem > id_rsa.pe
```

On client :

```
 1- get pem file

 2- chmod 400 id_rsa.pem

 For Testing Purpose :
 3- ssh -i id_rsa.pem <user>@<host>
```

---

In my case I am using Java to deploy the files so I used `sshj` to send files using `newSCPFileTransfer()` of sshj library.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to write a script or use Ansible. Both require ssh.
See [Ansible documentation here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/intro_getting_started.html) and
[Simple Ansible guide on tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansible/index.htm)

Comment: OMG, what's wrong with good 'ol `rsync`?

Comment: I'll read about Ansible, for now I'm using pem ssh keys